# What's the name of the grid-like layout used in Google+ apps?

Tags: android, layout, gridview, google-plus

I am thinking to build an app which will have the same grid layout like in the picture, but I cant figure out what layout I should use.

GridView, or something like that?

[image: Google plus]

Comment: Are you looking for a specific layout **name** or asking how to draw such layout?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the name is `CustomLayout` or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using StaggeredGridView . Check out below repos on github

https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView

https://github.com/chrisjenx/StaggeredGridView/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough to do it with LinearLayout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <!-- Stack rows vertically -->
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <!-- First row, two items -->
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <!-- First item, 50% of width -->
      <FooView android:id="@+id/foo1"
          android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <!-- Second item, 50% of width -->
      <FooView android:id="@+id/foo2"
          android:layout_width="0px"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Next row, just one item -->
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <!-- Third item, 100% of width -->
      <FooView android:id="@+id/foo2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- And so on... -->
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Obviously, the exact nature of "FooView" is up to you, as are decorative borders, shadows, etc.  In practice, you'd want to do this programatically, but this static xml layout shows you what you're after.

GridLayout also would work, but it's only available in 4.0 and above, unless you want to start using the compatibility library.  Since LinearLayout will do the job, that's what I would use.  RelativeLayout would probably also work, but I've never been able to get the damn thing to work, myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what they use, but you can achieve the same effect with either a `GridLayout` or a `ListView`.

Comment: i dont think that this is possible with listview

Comment: Sure it is -- you can have different item types in a ListView. You can display one view which displays only one item and one view which shows 2 items and display them alternately.